# Updating 4 rows in SQL Table with common table

Tags: php, sql

I have a PHP form that needs to update a SQL table the problem is I have 4 rows that have the same variable but need to update them all from a form in PHP with 4 different inputs

Here is a Snippet of the PHP Form

PHP FORM:

```
 <td><input name="member_id" type="hidden" id="member_id" value="<? echo    
 $rows['member_id']; ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Name</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="ussd_e1name" id="ussd_e1name" 
 value="<? echo $rows['ussd_e1name']; ?>" ></td>
                      <td>Surname</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="ussd_e1surname" id="ussd_e1surname" 
 value="<? echo $rows['ussd_e1surname']; ?>" ></td>
                      <td>Contact Nr</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="ussd_e1cell" id="ussd_e1cell" 
 value="<? echo $rows['ussd_e1cell']; ?>" ></td>
                    </tr>
```

This is partial of the form the PHP code to update the table is as follow:

PHP CODE:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE recipients set
        ussd_e1name = '".$ussd_e1name."',
        ussd_e1surname = '".$ussd_e1surname."',
        ussd_e1cell = '".$ussd_e1cell."',
        ussd_e1name2 = '".$ussd_e1name2."',
        ussd_e1surname2 = '".$ussd_e1surname2."',
        ussd_e1cell2 = '".$ussd_e1cell2."',
        ussd_e1name3 = '".$ussd_e1name3."',
        ussd_e1surname3 = '".$ussd_e1surname3."',
        ussd_e1cell3 = '".$ussd_e1cell3."',
        ussd_e1name4 = '".$ussd_e1name4."',
        ussd_e1surname4 = '".$ussd_e1surname4."',
        ussd_e1cell4 = '".$ussd_e1cell4."'
        WHERE member_id='" . $member_id . "'" ;
```

The table has one common and that is member_id so basically I need to update all 4 rows where the member_id is the same with the 4 inputs from the PHP form, each row has its unique ID as well but I cannot draw that ID as it differs so I filter on the member_id which is common lets say 123 in each row.

The 4 inputs is pushed via POST on the form

Comment: Is what kind of database this is a super secret or something? Makes it much harder to help you without that.

Comment: I only see 4 input fields in the html you posted. It does not match the number of variables you are using to build the SQL query (13).